# Alinhar botão submit junto com o input Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte código que utiliza bootstrap 3 que consiste de um input e de um botão de submit. Atualmente o botão esta abaixo do input, porém desejo que ele fique alinhado lateralmente com o input. Verifiquei algumas questões presentes aqui porém as respostas não resolviam o problema.

Código:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="span7 text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" style="float: none; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Opt1</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked="">Opt2</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Opt3</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

O site como esta
[image: Imagem de como esta]

O site como quero (botão search alinhado à direita e radio buttons centralizado entre o input e o button)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já experimentou colocar o botão dentro da `div` do formulário?

Comment: Sim, o botão fica "Colado abaixo do input"

Comment: Assim está bom? http://jsfiddle.net/a6Lt5Lgx/show/

Comment: Sim, como fez para ficar assim?

Comment: Postei como resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crie uma div com a classe `input-group` e adicione input e o botão dentro, use a classe `input-group-btn` na div onde o botão vai ficar.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Lt5Lgx/

Comment: como poderia aumentar o tamanho do input e do botão?

Comment: Na documentação tem as classes que você pode usar, pra [botão](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes) e [input](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes). Basta adicionar a classe.

Comment: Você saberia como centralizar verticalmente e horizontalmente?

Comment: Ricardo, eu nunca trabalhei com *bootstrap*, então não consigo ajudar muito, o pouco que sei é pesquisando! :/

Comment: Eu também não, hoje é meu terceiro dia trabalhando com bootstrap.

Comment: Boa sorte amigo! Creio que rapidamente você vai conseguir dominar. =)

Comment: @Ricardo você gostaria de centralizar o que ? O bootstap possuí a classe `text-center` para centralizar texto, é só colocar no "pai" que o texto ficará centralizado.